# std::vector pointer with data swap

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, new-operator, stdvector

In the section of code below, what would be the resultant memory structure after the swap?  Would there be a leak because they have swapped memory addresses underneath? Would it be fine because they did a deep copy? what if this code was stuck inside of a class and I was swapping a working buffer with a piece of dynamic memory?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> * ptr_str_vec =
        new std::vector<std::string>();
    ptr_str_vec->push_back("Hello");

    std::vector<std::string> str_vec;
    str_vec.push_back("World");

    ptr_str_vec->swap(str_vec);

    delete ptr_str_vec;
    //What would be the resulting structures?

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Posted slightly faulty code. Fixed the errors.

Comment: There is a leak because you `new`ed something and didn't call `delete`.

Comment: Assuming there were a delete for the ptr_str_vec, is there still a leak?

Comment: You obviously tried this under the debugger and saw the answer for yourself.  What's the real question?

Comment: `vector::swap` swaps the *contents* of the vectors; there's no such thing as *swapping addresses of the vectors* going on in your code.

Comment: No, there would be no leak.

Comment: @JohnDibling : I have run this through a debugger, but in a complex scenario in an asynchronous system. I wondered if the new operator had an affect on the swap method of a std::vector. I'm sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: No, I mean you ran the code that you posted and expected us to run.  You had to see that the contents of the vectors were swapped, and so this leads me to ask, what's your *real* question?  Because this clearly isn't it.

Comment: The new operator uses the heap for its storage and it can potentially outlive the current scope if it were put into a long running program. When you swap out its memory, does the str_vec re-use the memory allocated to it within its scope, or does it now point to the heap addresses and need to be deleted explicitly?

Comment: There certainly is no "deep copying" going on. The data of one vector is swapped with that of another. In practice this is as simple as a pointer swap. But whatever you are asking or trying to get at isn't clear at all. Bear in mind that each vector manages its own resources. Otherwise it would be unusable.

Comment: Leon Li got my answer below. Thank you all for clarity. Sorry if my question was murky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a vector is created, the underlying continuous data block used by vector is by default created from heap.  In your case, since you didn't supply allocator, default one is used.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> * ptr_str_vec =
        new std::vector<std::string>(); // #^&! *ptr_str_vec is allocated from heap. vector's data block is allocated from heap.
    ptr_str_vec->push_back("Hello");    // #^&! "hello" is copied onto heap block #1

    std::vector<std::string> str_vec;   // #^&! str_vec is allocated from stack. vector's data block is allocated from heap.
    str_vec.push_back("World");         // #^&! "world" is copied onto heap block #2

    ptr_str_vec->swap(str_vec);         // #^&! swap is fast O(1), as it is done by swapping block #1 and #2's address. No data copy is done during swap.

    delete ptr_str_vec;                 // #^&! delete ptr_str_vec as well as heap block #2.
    //What would be the resulting structures? /

    return 0;                           // #^&! delete str_vec as well as heap block #1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The values in each vector will be swapped http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/swap/

I see no memory leak (other than the one you get when your program ends at the end of main, since you aren't deleting your pointer), your ptr_str_vec pointer does not change, only the data inside the vector that it points to changes

Comment: Is that at all influenced by the new operator?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are already familiar with [swap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/swap/), is there any reason that you haven't set it up so you can test the output to see what it does yourself?  This will be the quickest way to assure yourself that you know exactly what it is doing and if your use of it is appropriate.

In this case, the resulting structures are simply that `ptr_str_vec` points to a vector containing a `std::string("World")` and `str_vec` is a vector containing a `std::string("Hello")`.  Your example suffers from many faults in answering your question, in particular because you only have a single element in each vector (and thus the vectors are equal length), and because the elements are the exact same size (and thus the vectors occupy approximately equivalent memory segments).  In a running instance of your full project, it is very likely that none of these conditions are true.